# Is it possible to draw function like tangens wihout knowing its domain?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, processing.js

I have a function that draw functions in processing.js like this:

```
var plot_line = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    line(x1+200, -y1+200, x2+200, -y2+200);
};

var plot = function (f, scale) {
    scale = scale || 1;
    for (var x=-200; x<200; x++) {
        var y1 = f(x/scale)*scale;
        var y2 = f((x+1)/scale)*scale;
        plot_line(x, y1, x+1, y2);
    }
};
```

but the function fail if I call `plot(Math.tan, 20);` because the function have Asymptotes, the ouput look like this:

[image: tangens]

Is it possible to have generic draw function that will work for functions like tangens?

Here is a [demo](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/plot/6405084394553344) the output should look like on [google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=pl&q=tan(x)) (without vertial lines where there are Asymptotes)

Comment: You mean "tangent"?  Those look correct to me.  Your angles should be in radians, not degrees.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what the problem is here? You've posted what happens- what did you expect to happen instead? And similar to your other question, can you please post a [mcve] that we can copy and paste to run ourselves?

Comment: @KevinWorkman added a demo and link to goole that show how the image should look like.

Comment: Can you not just figure out if you are sitting on a vertical asymptote (or will have crossed over it) and just not bother calling the plot function for that one iteration?

Comment: it is unclear if you are asking for removing lines from the plot, handling FPU overflow or for detecting ranges and scales of unknown function.